# Background Service application can be accessed by two applications

Tags: visual-studio, mobile, service, windows-phone, background-task

Can I create with Windows phone a Background Service application can be accessed by two other applications on the same device ?

Concept two applications communicate with a "background service" application

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can do it.

Take a look at this example:  [App Services sample for Windows 10](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServices)